# Predictive model using Keras and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

So I have created a predictive model using Keras, which has accuracy about 60%-65%.

So the data we pass is `xtst`,`xtrn`,`ytst`,`ytrn` to `train_test_split`, `test_split=.3` and so on, to train and test on supervised data. Now after all these I have a new set of data say `xnew`.

How do i use this data to predict the `y` values for this new data?

Where should i feed this `xnew` data for it to give me `y`?

The model:

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(10,input_shape=(4,),activation = 'relu') 
model.add(Dense(32,activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Dense(101,activation = 'softmax')) 

from keras import optimizers 
model.compile(Adam(lr=.01),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=20,epochs=40,shuffle=True,verbose=2) 
pred = model.predict(x_test,batch_size = 10,verbose = 2) 
for i in pred: 
  print(i)
```

Comment: basically you should use `y = model.predict(x)` if you provide your code maybe we could give you more specific solution, suggest to take a look at the keras docs also https://keras.io/

Comment: @shahaf That's the model I'm choosing

Comment: I see the model is categorial, right? meaning you choose from 101 different categories, is that right? can you provide a line of x,y input?

Answer (score 0):

When you have trained your model you can use `model.save(your_model_name.h5)` to save your model. Then you can load it again using `model = load_model(your_model_name.h5)`. From there you can use `model.predict(xnew)` or perhaps `model.predict_classes(xnew)` if you have made a classifier. I suggest that you look at the [Model API](https://keras.io/models/model/) also.

Answer (score 0):

for a multi-category classifier model with a `softmax` output layer you can train the model using those vectors

```
x => [....]             #some vector
y => [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,...]
```

where `y` is a vector indicating the probabilities of each category

to predict given some `x` like `y = model.predict(x)` you will get a probabilities vector like this `[0.1, 0.05, 0.5, ....]` you simply need to find the index with the max probability, you can use `category = numpy.argmax(y)`

Comment: the first data i trained the model with say has the input shape 400x700 should the new data which I am giving also have the same input shape? If so, how can we always make sure that it is going to be that way.

Comment: I don't know exactly what do you mean... but you suppose to build the model based on the data dim you have if you have a data of shape 400x700 than you need 400 node in the input layer, if you have 300x800 than 300 node should consist the input layer, the y dim correspond to the output layer